# My SUM(total) shows sum of all users

Tags: php, row

I got it working to show the total sum. But it includes all users. I wanted it to show total sum by logged in user only. Please help me!

```
<?php  
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
  foreach($conn->query('SELECT total FROM event') as $row) {  
  echo "<td><span style=font-weight:bold> " . number_format($row['total'],2) . "</span></td>";  
  }  
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT total FROM event WHERE user_id = LOGGED_IN_USER_ID`

Comment: What's you're 'event' table's structure like ? How do you identify a user in this table ?

Comment: Users are identified by username. $_SESSION['username']. The structure is entryID, artistName, venue, eventDate, username, seat, price, quantity, total.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php  
  $user_id = 5; //set login user id here
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
  foreach($conn->query('SELECT COUNT(event_id) as total FROM event WHERE user_id ='.$user_id) as $row) {  
    echo "<td><span style=font-weight:bold>" . number_format($row['total'], 2) . "</span></td>";  
  }  
?>
```

Comment: Try update field name in this query and run into phpmyadmin, check results: 
 `SELECT COUNT(event_id) as total FROM event WHERE user_id =5`

Comment: I got this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

use this query get current user total

```
"Select sum(total) from event where name='$_SESSION['username']'";
```

use this url:http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
<?php  $user_id = 1;
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(event_id) as total FROM event WHERE user_id =".$user_id);
$query_data = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo "<td><span style=font-weight:bold>". number_format($query_data['total'], 2) . "</span></td>";  ?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I got this -> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Comment: Hi can your please show the structure of your table.. 
This error appear we get when you use wrong column name.
Or some item is not found in db